# Ошибка при загрузке конструктора формы С++\CLI

Tags: c++-cli

Делаю проект в Visual-Studio 2008 C++\CLI. После объявления переменной в классе

```
public: int index;
```

Появляется ошибка при загрузке конструктора формы. При этом проект компилируется и нормально работает. Пробовал ипользовать тип System::Int32, все то же самое.

```
C++ CodeDOM parser error: Line: 111, Column: 25 --- Unknown type 'int'. Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced. If this type is a part of your development project, make sure that the project has been successfully built.
```

Как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто нет там управляемого типа int. С++/CLI это не С++. По [ссылке](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/0wf2yk2k.aspx) видно, что вместо `int` нужно писать `System.Int32`.

NB: я не говорю, что в c++/cli нет `int`. Просто не в каждом куске кода его можно писать.

Comment: Через точку тип вообще не определяется, а через :: определяется, но ошибка в конструкторе остается.

Comment: проблема магическим способом решилась. объявление в виде:

public: int index;